# Ajaxing in functions.php

Tags: ajax, wp-localize-script

To ajax filtered posts, I needed to put most of my `index.php` template into the `functions.php` file ([followed this tutorial](http://bobz.co/ajax-filter-posts-tag/)) and do from there.

But now javascript won't work - basically the accordion style listings won't open and close like they did before, trailers won't embed, etc. Click on a tag to demo [here](http://pigcine.pamrosel.com).

Is there something wrong with how I'm calling js / do I need to `wp_localize_script` to get it working? Sorry I'm very new to this and Google hasn't helped because I think I'm out of my depth.

How I'm calling JS scripts:

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'style.css', get_stylesheet_uri() ); 

wp_register_script('jquery_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery_script');

wp_register_script('my_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js');
wp_enqueue_script('my_script');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

What is in `script.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Open and close screelistings
$('.sl').find('.sl_closed').click(function(){

//Expand or collapse this panel
$(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

//Hide the other panels
$(".sl_open").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');          
});

//Added class for opened and closed screenlistings

$(".sl").click(function(e) {
var isActive = $(this).hasClass('sl_active');
$('.sl_active').removeClass('sl_active');
$('.active').removeClass('active');
if (!isActive) {
  $(this).addClass('sl_active');
  $(this).find('.sl_closed').addClass('active');
}
});

// Replace feature image with trailer 

$('img').click(function(){
video = '<iframe src="'+ $(this).attr('data-video') +'"></iframe>'; 
$(this).replaceWith(video);
});

});
```

Comment: the accordion works well on this page : http://pigcine.pamrosel.com/

Comment: Your script.js is actually empty http://pigcine.pamrosel.com/wp-content/themes/html5-boilerplate-for-wordpress-master/js/script.js?ver=4.5.3

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace `$(document).ready(function() {` with `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`
It should work for you.